# How to convert a string in .ics file and then download it in Flask?

Tags: python

I am new to flask and I want to download a string after converting it in to `.ics` file in flask.

I get the data in to string format by this method:

```
my_data = get_content()
```

Now, I want to convert into the `.ics` file and download it using streaming content in flask.

Currently, I am using

```
return Response(my_data, mimetype,)
```

but the file is dispalyed in the browser. How can I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Disposition` header in the response to serve the file as a download.

```
return Response(my_date, mimetype, {'Content-Disposition':'attachment'})
```

If you are reading the file from disk, use flask's `send_file` method

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file